# Highcharts, multi stacked bar with shared legend items

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've this set of data that is

```
                            Serie 1    Serie 2
Category 1     2005         20         10              
               2006         30         15
Category 2     2005         35         17
               2006         25         12
```

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/X4g4Q/

I've checked options like giving the series ids and things like linkedTo http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.linkedTo

But I've found not a single way in which I can have multiple stacked bars that 'share' a legend item (thus color). Am I formatting my data incorrectly or is this simply not possible using highcharts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`linkedTo` options allows you to have one legend item for n-series. It's not about series colors. If you want to use the same color, set it directly for series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6bgvz/

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors; // get colors

// in options:

series: [{ 
    color: colors[0]
}, { 
    colors: colors[1]
} ... ]
```

Comment: agreed. That's clear to me. But does this mean that there is no way to get highcharts to 'understand' that both bars 'share' their stacked elements?

Comment: There's no such option. Series are independant, you can connect only their legend items and axes (by setting in series `x/yAxis: index` for both to be the same). If you have always only two series, then you can workaround issue with colors by setting only two colors, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6bgvz/1/ (line no. 8).

Answer (score 2):

You can hide two series in the legend (which are the same name), catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and combine show/hide action.

```
events:{
                legendItemClick:function(){
                    var name = this.name,
                        series = this.chart.series;

                    $.each(series, function(i,serie){
                        if(serie.name == name) {
                            if(serie.visible)
                                serie.hide();
                            else
                                serie.show();
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X4g4Q/3/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `linkedTo:':previous',` . Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chofer/XmctB/)

Comment: That's no solution as the colors are still different. Actually I think this behavior is a bug as clicking the legend on a color will hide 2 colors (including a different one).

Comment: You can set color for each serie and then linked to legend id or previous legend . I update the fiddle